# PAD file download URL

Tags: specifications, pad-xml

The PAD spec (http://pad.asp-software.org/spec/spec.php) defines the download URL as follows:
URL ftp or http:// + 2-120 characters with extension exe, zip, or other
And the regex pattern used is:

```
^((http|ftp):\/\/.{2,120}\.(air|apk|app|bin|com|exe|dmg|hqx|gz|g
zip|jar|msi|rar|sea|sh|sis|sit|sitx|tar|taz|tgx|tgz|uu|z|zip))?\
```

What happens if the  download url does not have extensions listed above?
My site has a download page where the php script tracks each software download. If I provide a link to just the binary I lose the ability to track downloads. On the other hand I'm not sure what happens if the PAD file is not to spec.

Answer (score 1):

Why not handle the download via a RewriteRule that forwards a given directory stub to your PHP script? This will be transparent to the caller and allow you to do whatever you want in your script.

For example:

```
RewriteRule \A/downloads/((?!\.php).)*$     /downloads/index.php    [L]
```

You could then access the requested URL (and hence derive the required file, etc.) via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: Interesting, that might work, let me try it, thank you very much

Comment: I got this to work :
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^downloads/.*$  download.php    [L] 
</IfModule>
Thank you very much for help!

Comment: @AndyM That's the .htaccess format. (Using ^ instead of \A/, etc.) Glad this solution works for you.